# Erro ao remover Child em lista (li) JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Amigos! o código que tenho é esse abaixo, mas quando eu removo todos os items da lista, ou seja todas as `<li>` com a função, eu queria que aparecesse a mensagem de `alert`, quando a pessoa pressionasse novamente o botão de Limpar Lista, só que ao invés disso, aparece um erro que é o seguinte:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at HTMLInputElement.removeElement (script.js:26)`

```
const $list = document.querySelector('ul')
const $product = document.querySelector('#product')
const $btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const $reset = document.querySelector('#reset')
 
$btn.addEventListener('click', adcProduct)
 
function adcProduct() {
    const $item = `<li>${$product.value}</li>`
    $list.innerHTML += $item
    $product.value = ''
    $product.focus()
}
 
$product.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        adcProduct()
    }
})
 
$reset.addEventListener('click', removeElement)
 
function removeElement() {
    // Removes an element from the document
    const $ul = document.getElementById("list");
    $ul.removeChild($ul.children[0])
    if($product = '') {
        alert('A lista está vazia')
    }
}
```

Comment: $ul.removeChild($ul.[0]) testa assim

Comment: Germano, não deu certo aqui a sua solução. Também não entendi pq fui negativado, pois se perguntei é pq não achei a solução em nenhum lugar e já tentei de tudo.

Comment: http://devfuria.com.br/javascript/dom-remove-child/ de uma olhada nesse link,acredito que vai te ajudar

Comment: Você vai ter que passar qual nó da lista você quer remover, não o valor

Comment: Mas aí que está! Eu consigo remover os nós/node, o que não consigo é que após remover os nós e não ter mais nenhum para remover, ao usuário pressionar o botão de remover novamente, apareça uma mensagem de alert, avisando que não há mais items a ser removidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia, com base nos seus comentários entendi o seu problema, cheguei a essa resolução :

```
if ($ul.children[0]) {
    $ul.removeChild($ul.children[0])
} else {
alert('A lista está vazia');
}
```

antes de remover o produto da lista, eu testo se ele existe, caso exista vai exclui-lo da lista, e caso não exista exibe o `alert` que você deseja
Caso queria ver rodando fiz um exemplo rodando no link abaixo:
https://playcode.io/646420/

Comment: Deu tudo certo aqui, com a sua solução. Muito obrigado, já não sabia mais o que fazer hehe

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha conseguido te ajudar, você também contribuiu para que conseguisse...